# VS Code API returning unknown URL scheme with URI

Tags: visual-studio-code, uri, vscode-extensions

I'm sorry that title was kindof confusing. Here is the gist of the issue I've been running into and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. I am trying to write a simple VS Code extension that opens a webview that contains a local JS file:

```
//CODE SNIPPET #1
const jsFilePath = vscode.Uri.file(
    path.join(context.extensionPath, 'src', 'assets', 'script.js')
);
const jsFileSrc = currentPanel.webview.asWebviewUri(jsFilePath);
//Pass the jsFileSrc URI as a parameter to getWebViewContent so that I can add the URI to the <script> tag that call the JS.
currentPanel.webview.html = getWebViewContent(jsFileSrc);
```

Simple Enough, and it works perfectly by itself. The next step is that I need to check the users current project file structure for a specific folder (and eventually pull a .txt file out of that folder and use it in the Javascript).

```
//CODE SNIPPET #2
//Check that the Annotations folder exists
const rootFolderPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath + "/annotations";
if(fs.existsSync(rootFolderPath)){
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Folder Was Found!");
    return true;
} else {
    vscode.window.showErrorMessage("No folder titled 'annotations' found in root path " + vscode.workspace.rootPath + ". Please close the extension and try again.");
    return false;
}
```

This also seemed pretty simple too, it just checks to see if the "annotations" folder exists in the workspace. And this all works perfectly fine if I place code snippet #2 UNDERNEATH code snippet #1. However the second I place code snippet #2 anywhere above code snippet #1, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

This is the URL that is appended to the HTML document each time I run the web view. Again, when I put code snippet 1 before code snippet 2, it works perfectly fine, but when I reverse the order I get the Unknown URL Scheme error--even though the same URL is returned each time.

> vscode-resource://file///Users/user/Desktop/Project/NLP/Webviewer/rule-editor/src/assets/script.js

I've read through a good amount of the documentation and I can't seem to figure out why this is the case. I need to be able to check for this folder and retrieve the .txt file inside of this folder so I can add it to the webview. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have discovered the issue. It appears that fs.existsSync is deprecated. For the VS Code api, it is better to use vscode.workspace.fs (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs).

This is the revised edition of code snippet #2 for anyone running into the same issue, this might help you get on the right track.

```
var rootPath: string;
if(vscode.workspace.rootPath){
    rootPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath.toString();
    const rootFolderPath = vscode.Uri.file(
        path.join(rootPath, 'annotations')
    );
    vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory(rootFolderPath).then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            //This will print out a list of all the files inside of the dir.
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
}
```